# Unique extrema of sum of monotonically increasing and decreasing functions on an interval

Tags: analysis, optimization

If I have two functions, f and g, defined on the interval [0, 1]

with both f and g non negative (i.e. f(x), g(x) >= 0)

f(x) is monotonically increasing, while g(x) is monotonically decreasing.

and

h(x) = f(x) + g(x)

I believe it is 'obvious' that h will have a single local maximum or minimum in the interval (although possibly on the boundary).

Is this actually true?

EDIT: Corrected that g is decreasing, not increasing

What I want to use this for is to say that in this situation described above, if one finds any local minimum to h, then that is the minimum of h over the entire interval.

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ both strictly increasing? If so, then there will be a single local minimum at $x=0$ and a single local maximum at $x=1$. If they are not strictly increasing, then it need not be true, e.g. what if $f$ and $g$ are both constant?

Comment: Most unfortunately, that was a typo. g should be DEcreasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly not true. Let $f$ alternate between increasing slowly and increasing quickly, let $g$ alternate between decreasing quickly and decreasing slowly, and you can have as many local extrema as you want.

Comment: While that sounds quite compelling, I am unable to construct an example. Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: Draw two *increasing* curves that cross each other several times. Now let one of them be $f$, and let the other be $-g$.

Comment: Ok, that does it. Taking f = x and g = 2 + a - x - sin(x) we have that f and g are both non negative and monotonic. h = 2 + a -sin(x), which has many minima and maxima on any interval [0,a].

Comment: Moreover take $g(x)=a-f(x)$ such that $a\ge f(x)$,. Then $f(x)+g(x)=constant$.